# How can I show current version during dnf update/check-update

Tags: fedora, dnf

Is there any option to add column with current version in dnf after invoking `update`/`check-update` operation? By default list contains only package name, new version and repository.

Comment: you can check manually using `dnf info package_name` but it is probably not what you want to hear.

Comment: Any progress in DNF to be able to show current and available version of the package before upgrade?